# Random access to D3D11 buffer with R8G8B8A8_UNorm format in HLSL

Tags: directx, directx-11, hlsl

I have a D3D11 buffer with a few million elements that is supposed to hold data in the `R8G8B8A8_UNorm` format.

The desired behavior is the following: One shader calculates a `vec4` and writes it to the buffer in a random access pattern. In the next pass, another shader reads the data in a random access pattern and processes them further.

My best guess would be to create an `UnorderedAccessView` with the `R8G8B8A8_UNorm` format. But how do I declare the `RWBuffer<?>` in HLSL, and how do I write to and read from it? Is it necessary to declare it as `RWBuffer<uint>` and do the packing from `vec4` to `uint` manually?

In OpenGL I would create a buffer and a buffer texture. Then I can declare an `imageBuffer` with the `rgba8` format in the shader, access it with `imageLoad` and `imageStore`, and the hardware does all the conversions for me. Is this possible in D3D11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little tricky due to a lot of different gotchas, but you should be able to do something like this.

In your shader that writes to the buffer declare:

```
RWBuffer<float4> WriteBuf : register( u1 );
```

Note that it is bound to register `u1` instead of `u0`. Unordered access views (UAV) must start at slot 1 because the `u#` register is also used for render targets.

To write to the buffer just do something like:

```
WriteBuf[0] = float4(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1);
```

Note that you must write all 4 values at once.

In your C++ code, you must create an unordered access buffer, and bind it to a UAV. You can use the `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` format. When you write 4 floats to it, the values will automatically be converted and packed. The UAV can be bound to the pipeline using `OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews`.

In your shader that reads from the buffer declare a read only buffer:

```
Buffer<float4> ReadBuf : register( t0 );
```

Note that this buffer uses `t0` because it will be bound as a shader resource view (SRV) instead of UAV.

To access the buffer use something like:

```
float4 val = ReadBuf[0];
```

In your C++ code, you can bind the same buffer you created earlier to an SRV instead of a UAV. The SRV can be bound to the pipeline using `PSSetShaderResources` and can also be created with `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`.

You can't bind both the SRV and UAV using the same buffer to the pipeline at the same time. So you must bind the UAV first and run your first shader pass. Then unbind the UAV, bind SRV, and run the second shader pass.

There are probably other ways to do this as well. Note that all of this requires shader model 5.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly :)
One small followup question: I programmed the thing without specifying any "registers" and it works nonetheless (note that I used the Effects framework). What is the point in specifying them?

Comment: If you don't specify registers, they are just automatically assigned when the shader is compiled. Specifying them explicitly just gives you more control over where they go which is useful if you need it when binding the data from C++. It's probably not as important with the Effects framework because you can just grab everything by name. Without the Effects framework you bind things  in C++ by the register slot number (unless you've used shader reflection to mimic the Effects framework).